# curl Command using spring rest template

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, curl

I am posting JSON originally via terminal, which looks like this

```
curl http://api_server_address:port/api/v1/addmos_getAllVMMetadata -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' --data 'v1'
```

And below what the code looks like using spring

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    String input = "v1";
    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(input, headers);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Container container = restTemplate.postForObject("http://192.168.100.14:15001/api/v1/addmos_getAllVMMetadata", request, Container.class);
    List<Tenant> tenants = container.getData().getTenants();
    System.out.println("Tenant Size: " + tenants.size());
```

But when I run, hit the error NullPointer at the line getdata from gettenants. I already made a class for getData and getTenants as well.

```
public class Data {
private List<Tenant> tenants = new ArrayList<Tenant>();

public List<Tenant> getTenants() {
    return tenants;
}

public void setTenants(List<Tenant> tenants) {
    this.tenants = tenants;
}
```

}

```
public class Data {
private List<Tenant> tenants = new ArrayList<Tenant>();

public List<Tenant> getTenants() {
    return tenants;
}

public void setTenants(List<Tenant> tenants) {
    this.tenants = tenants;
}
```

}

This is what my data structure would be look like.

[link to the data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk8Sb.jpg)

But I got below error when trying to run the code. Is there something I've missed?

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.itri.openstacktopology.OpenstacktopologyclientApplication.main(OpenstacktopologyclientApplication.java:28)

Comment: did you inspect value after     Container container = restTemplate.postForObject("http://192.168.100.14:15001/api/v1/addmos_getAllVMMetadata", request, Container.class); call

Comment: @spandey15 i print some string after the Container container = .... and it can be printed. but still null pointer exception at line List<Tenant> tenants = container.getData().getTenants();

Comment: looks like your services are not returning response properly what you are extracting

Comment: @spandey15 but if I check the command directly from my terminal, I got the results

Comment: ok. now compare your payload and java object compatibility

Comment: possibly share your rest response too.